# theano.gradient.DisconnectedInputError in VAE (python)

Tags: python, keras, theano, keras-layer, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement a VAE on keras, and the following is a snippet of the code I've written.

```
z_mean = Dense( self.z_dim , init=initialization , activation='linear')(H2)   
z_mean = LeakyReLU(alpha=.001)(z_mean)  
z_log_var = Dense( self.z_dim,init=initialization , activation='linear')(H2)  
z_log_var = LeakyReLU(alpha=.001)(z_log_var)  
z = Lambda(self.sampling ,  output_shape=K.int_shape(z_mean) )([z_mean, z_log_var])  
H3 = Dense(input_dim - 1, init=initialization , activation='linear')(z)
```

Now when I compile the model:

```
model = Model(input=data_input, output=[xh , z_mean , z_log_var ] )  
grads = K.gradients(cost, trainable_vars)
```

it gives me the error:
**theano.gradient.DisconnectedInputError:

Backtrace when that variable is created:

H3 = Dense(input_dim - 1, init=initialization , activation='linear')(z)**

Does anyone have any idea why this error? 
My guess is that the gradient fail to apply from the z to z_mean and z_log_var

Comment: where did you defined `initialization` it is not in the code?

Comment: **"glorot_uniform"**, the code is just the basic implementation. It doesn't have the syntax error, and every variable is properly initialized.